# How can i make a command that shows a random percentage in the response? Discord python

Tags: discord, discord.py

Okay, So I want to make a command for a discord bot I am making where when the user does the command the bot responds with "Your shiprate is [random percentage]" how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the random library functions. Such as `randint()`. [w3Schools on randint()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_randint.asp)

```
import random
@bot.command()
async def commandName(ctx):
    percentage = (random.randint(0, 100))
    await ctx.send(f'Your shiprate is {percentage}')
```